# p5.js Safari play() pause() jump() problem

Tags: safari, soundcloud, p5.js

I am trying to make an audioplayer using the [p5.js Javascript Library](https://p5js.org/) and [Soundcloud API](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/guide). Most of it works well, but I am encountering some minor problems in the Safari Browser.

[This is the website](https://dooper.io/teduur) and the javascript file with all the functions is [sketch.js](https://dooper.io/teduur/js/sketch.js).

There is a progressbar on the website and when clicked it should [jump](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5.SoundFile/jump) to a point in the song.

```
var progressBar = document.getElementById('progressBar');
```

```
progressBar.addEventListener("click", function(progbar) {
  var percent = (progbar.offsetX / this.offsetWidth);
  sound.jump(sound.duration() * percent);
  sound.onended(endSong);
}, false);
```

In Firefox it works as expected as long `sound.playMode('restart')` is set. But Safari creates an `InvalidStateError`

When `sound.playMode('sustain')` is set both Firefox and Safari equally [jump](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5.SoundFile/jump) to a point in the song but the song is played twice.

Does anybody have a clue what might be wrong here?

Comment: From the sound of what you are doing, restart should be the mode to use. I believe the behaviour you are seeing for sustain is expected, judging from documentation.

Comment: I found out that there might be a bug in the p5.sound file: https://github.com/processing/p5.js-sound/issues/372

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the following workaround for Safari, Firefox and Chrome:

```
progressBar.addEventListener("click", function(progbar) {
  percent = (progbar.offsetX / this.offsetWidth);
  setTimeout(function(){
    Object.assign(sound, {_playing: true});
    sound.playMode('restart');
  }, 100);
  sound.stop();
  sound.playMode('sustain');
  sound.jump(sound.duration() * percent);
}, false);
```